# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have the following snippet from a script

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('tok.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'])
```

This is for auth in google analytics
But when I run the script on my site, the logs report the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tok.json'
```

I tried putting tok.json in all places (directories?) I can think of on the server, but the error does not disappear

Comment: What do you get from [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)?

Comment: Does your your web server have the rights to read your tok.json file ?

Comment: how i can check rights?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error. I found out that if I cd into the directory before running the program it runs fine. But obviously, that's not something you'd want to manually do every time. So, I adjusted the file.json to include the absolute path to the file. In other words:

Instead of:

```
'tok.json'
```

I changed it to:

```
'user/folder/tok.json'
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it since it will break if you ever move the files to a new directory, but it worked for me.

I think the problem is that when the program runs it's looking in whatever folder the terminal/server is currently in, not necessarily in the program's folder. So you have to explicitly tell it where to go.

Comment: i had to use the full path too. getting google sheets API to work.