# Pyinstaller not able to add Icon on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, icons, pyinstaller

I tried referencing my icon file in my `.spec` like this:

```
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='PubData',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          icon='C:\\Users\\mksmasr\\Desktop\\PubDataNewest\\PubData-master\\PubDataLogo.ico')
```

when running pyinstaller i get the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PubDataLogo.ico'

After looking around on SO (the following links):

[Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669782/python-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

[FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .constants.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076319/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-constants-json)

I have not found any solution to help, I have even regenerated the files multiple times to make sure they aren't corrupt, also I tried using a relative reference in the `.spec` vs an absolute reference, it didn't seem to make a difference. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try having the icon path as a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals). Should be `icon=r"C:\\Users\\mksmasr\\Desktop\\PubDataNewest\\PubData-master\\PubDataLogo.ico"`.

Comment: i still cant get it to work, i tried that

Comment: Can you post your full spec file please?